# How do I convert the value from string to int using Automapper and using ForPath

Tags: c#

welcome everybody
How do I convert the value from string to int using Automapper and  using  ForPath

As in the following example

```
    public class test1
    {
       public Address Address { get; set; }
      

    }


    public class test2
    {
       public UserDto UserDto { get; set; }
       public string  Name { get; set; }
    }

    public class Address
    {
       public int u_id { get; set; }
       public string street { get; set; }
       public string Region { get; set; }
    }

    public class UserDto
    {
       public string id { get; set; }
    }


    public class StringToInt : IValueConverter<string, int>
    {
        public int Convert(string source, ResolutionContext context)
        {
            return int.TryParse(source == null ? "" : source, out var __source__) ? __source__ :default;
        }
    }

    public class IntToString : IValueConverter<int, string>
    {
        public string Convert(int source, ResolutionContext context)
        {
            return source.ToString();
        }
    }


    public static Mapper Request()
    {
        var config = new MapperConfiguration(cfg =>
        cfg.CreateMap<test1, test2>()
        .ForMember(DESTINATION => DESTINATION.UserDto.id, Source => Source.ConvertUsing(new IntToString(), src => src.Address.u_id ))
       // .ForPath(DESTINATION => DESTINATION.UserDto.id, Source => Source.ConvertUsing(new IntToString(), src => src.Address.u_id ))
          
        .ForAllOtherMembers(x => x.Ignore())
        );

        var mapper = new Mapper(config);
        return mapper;
    }


    public static Mapper Response()
    {
        var config = new MapperConfiguration(cfg =>
        cfg.CreateMap<test2, test1>()
        .ForMember(DESTINATION => DESTINATION.Address.u_id , Source => Source.ConvertUsing(new StringToInt(), src => src.UserDto.id))
        //.ForPath(DESTINATION => DESTINATION.Address.u_id , Source => Source.ConvertUsing(new StringToInt(), src => src.UserDto.id))
        .ForAllOtherMembers(x => x.Ignore())
        );

        var mapper = new Mapper(config);
        return mapper;
    }
```

If use ForMember Get an Exception

{"Expression 'DESTINATION => DESTINATION.test1.id ' must resolve to top-level member and not any child object's properties. You can use ForPath, a custom resolver on the child type or the AfterMap option instead.\r\n: lambdaExpression"}

How can I make a conversion only one property using ForPath and not using ForMember

Comment: That mapping is built-in, you don't need `ForMember` or `ForPath`.

Comment: Thanks for your response sir, how will the convert  only one property if using ForPath. Thank you again